# Automation using selenium with Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

**Consider the following image:**

[image]

How can I automate this functionality on this website?

I want to assert weather the error message appears, or not on wrong reference number input. The problem is, I can't find the locator. Can not click on message the, which is disappearing in a few seconds.

Comment: This is not a code writing service. What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Why is this tagged maven and testng?

Comment: Thanks Robert, I didn't mean for code, I want to assert that when user enter wrong reference number and click on login then one error message is appearing. I want to assert that error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message that you are trying to capture is an attribute of the webelement (Booking reference Text box). what you will have to do is

1. Get the webelement first
2. Then get its attribute('oninvalid').
3. Validate the actual value of the attribute vs Expected value of the attribute

This is the sample code.

```
WebElement weBookingReference_TextBox = driver.findElement(By.id("js-reference-field-with-letters"));
String strTemp = weBookingReference_TextBox.getAttribute("oninvalid");
System.out.println(strTemp);
```

Output:

> setCustomValidity('Your booking reference starts with LVE or LOV and
>   can be found on your booking summary. If you haven’t received your
>   booking summary yet, you’ll be unable to login to Manage My Booking.')

Hope this helps.